# Solve $ \lim_{x \to a}\sin{x} $

Tags: calculus, limits, trigonometry

I have a problem understanding a couple of steps in the following solved example we have in our course material

---

Solve

$$ \lim_{x \to a}\sin{x} $$

Since $\sin{x}\le x$ for all $x\ge0$ and since $\sin{x}=-\sin{x}$, we get
$$-|x|\le \sin{x}\le |x|.$$

Since $$\lim_{x\to 0}|x|=\lim_{x\to 0}-|x|=0$$
by the squeeze theorem
$$\lim_{x\to 0}\sin{x}=0.$$

By trigonometry $\cos{x}=1-2\sin^2(\frac{x}{2})$ hence

$$\lim_{x\to 0}\cos{x}=\lim_{x\to 0}(1-2\sin^2(\frac{x}{2}))=1-2\lim_{x\to 0}(\sin^2(\frac{x}{2}))=1-2(\lim_{x\to 0}\sin(\frac{x}{2}))^2=1.$$

By trigonometry

$$ \sin{x}=\sin({x-a+a})=\sin({x-a})\cos{a}+\cos({x-a})\sin{a}. $$

Now

$$ \lim_{x\to a}\sin{x}=\cos{a}\lim_{x\to a}\sin({x-a})+\sin{a}\lim_{x\to a}\cos({x-a}). $$

Since we already know that

$$\lim_{x\to a}\sin({x-a})=0$$ and $$\lim_{x\to a}\cos({x-a})=1,$$

we can conclude that

$$\lim_{x\to a}\sin{x}=\sin{a}.$$

---

My questions regarding this example:

1. From which trigonometric rule we got $\cos{x}=1-2\sin^2(\frac{x}{2})$?
2. How did we get $\sin({x-a+a})=\sin({x-a})\cos{a}+\cos({x-a})\sin{a}$?

Comment: From the trigonometric double-angle and angle-addition identities http://mathworld.wolfram.com/TrigonometricAdditionFormulas.html

Comment: It's worth noting that this is immediately implied (by definition!) by the fact that $\sin$ is continuous at $a$.

Comment: @DanielLittlewood: the strategy mentioned in question is one of the ways of proving continuity of $\sin$ function (depending on one of its suitable definitions). Easier approach is to consider the difference formula $\sin x-\sin a=2\cos((x+a)/2)\sin((x-a)/2)$ and use the inequality $|\sin x|\leq |x|$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> $$\cos 2y=\cos^2 y-\sin^2 y \implies\cos{x}=1-2\sin^2(\frac{x}{2})$$
>
> $$\sin {(y+z)}=\sin y \cos z + \sin z \cos y \\\implies \sin({x-a+a})=\sin({x-a})\cos{a}+\cos({x-a})\sin{a}$$

**NOTE**

The limit
$$lim_{x \to a}\sin{x}=\sin a$$
prove that $\sin x$ is a **continuos function** $\forall x \in \mathbb{R}$

Answer (score 1):

1. The cosine double angle formula
   $$\cos(2y) = 1-2\sin^{2}(y)$$
   with $y=\frac{1}{2}x$, and
2. The sine addition formula,
   $$\sin(A+B) = \sin(A)\cos(B)+\cos(A)\sin(B)$$
   with $A= x-a$ and $B=a$.

Answer (score 0):

For the first question we used the rule that $\cos(2x) = \cos^2(x) - \sin^2(x) = 1 - 2 \sin^2(x)$, where in the last equation we used the basic identity $\sin^2(x) + \cos^2(x) = 1$

In the second one we used the fact that $\sin(x+y) = \sin(x)\cos(y) + \sin(y)\cos(x)$

Answer (score 0):

Note that the following formulae hold: $$\sin(\alpha+\beta) = \sin \alpha \cos \beta + \cos \alpha \sin \beta$$ $$\cos(\alpha+\beta)=\cos \alpha \cos \beta -\sin \alpha \sin \beta$$

For part $1$, use the second equation, putting $\alpha=\beta$ and also, the fact, $\sin^2 \alpha+\cos^2 \alpha = 1$. Then, use $\beta=\frac{x}{2}$ to get an expression for $\cos x$.

For part $2$, use the first equation, where $x-a\equiv \alpha$ and $a \equiv \beta$.